# Prove that if $YA\cdot YB=YX\cdot YM$ then $(A,B;X,Y)=-1$ .

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given 4 collinear points $A,X,B,Y$  in this order. Let $ M$ be the midpoint of $AB$.  Prove that if $$YA\cdot YB=YX\cdot YM$$  then $(A,B;X,Y)=-1$ .

I think its related with orthogonality but couldn't proceed much, so went with a different route.

I tried directly solving , so I took $YA\cdot YB=YX\cdot YM \implies (AX+XY)YB=(BX+BU)(XY+MX)\implies AX\cdot BY= BX(XY+MX)+BY\cdot MX \implies AM\cdot BY=BX\cdot MY \implies BM\cdot BY=BX\cdot MY$.

But, I am not able to proceed. Any hints ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another proof (your approach of directly solving, just breaking the factors differently):

$$YA\cdot YB = YM\cdot YX \\ \implies (AX+XY)BY=(YA-AM)(YB+BX) \\ \implies AX\cdot BY +XY\cdot BY= AY\cdot BY - AM\cdot BY - AM\cdot BX + AY\cdot BX \\ \implies  AX\cdot BY - AY\cdot BX = AY\cdot BY-XY\cdot BY+AM\cdot (-BX-BY)\\= AY\cdot BY - XY\cdot BY - AM\cdot XY\\ = AY\cdot BY - XY\cdot (AM+BY) \\=AY\cdot BY -XY\cdot (BM+BY) \\ = AY\cdot BY - XY\cdot MY =0 \ (given)\\ \implies AX\cdot BY - AY\cdot BX =0$$

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Given $YA\cdot YB=YX\cdot YM$, we are able to construct the picture as above. Let ${AH\over HB}=r$, then $${AY\over BY} = {AY\over HY}\times {HY\over BY} = r^2$$

$${AX\over BX} = {AM\times AX\over BM\times BX} ={AZ\times AH\over BW\times BH} = ({AH\over BH})^2=r^2$$

Therefore $${AX\over BX} = {AY\over BY}$$

Comment: Of course not. I use the filling tool provided by the software to fill in a circle selection and then white out a smaller inner circle and then use the transformation tool to amplify the circle. Unfortunately the original circle was too small so after enlargement it appears zigzaggy.

Comment: Great solution! I learned a lot. :)

Comment: This solution is truly beautiful. I wanted to use the power-of-point looking thing, but the radical axis snaps everything into place. :D

Answer (score 3):

By an affine transformation you may map $Y$ to $0$ and $X$ to $1$ (this does not affect the claim). Let $a$ and $b$ be the (new) coordinates of $A$ and $B$. Then
$$ a  b =  m= \frac12(a+b)  \Leftrightarrow
\frac{a-1}{b-1}\frac{b}{a}=-1.$$
This also holds for complex scalars b.t.w.

Comment: [+1]. A little remark: you should change your first sentence into something like "You may take coordinates on the line in such a way that the abscissas of $Y,X$ are resp. $0,1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Thanks, it wasn't really a translation.

Comment: Great proof!!! I loved this trick of coordinates..

Answer (score 1):

First, we note that the [angle-bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) implies that (assuming that $A',X',B',Y'$ are collinear in that order)

$$X',Y' \text{ are the points where the internal and external bisectors of $\angle C'$ cut $A'B'$ in $\Delta A'B'C'$ }\iff (A',B';X',Y')=-1 \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)$$.
Now,

> $A,B,X$ are given as in your problem, so $M$ is fixed, and the product relation fixes $Y$ on the line containing $A,X,B$.

So, proving your problem is equivalent to proving that in any triangle $A'B'C'$ with points named as in $(1)$, the point $Y$ lying on the ray $A'X'B'$ satisying $YA'\cdot YB'=YM'\cdot YX'$ is precisely the point $Y'$ ($M'$ midpoint of $A'B'$).

So, we can just take a triangle (and hence assume it's sidelengths $a',b',c'$ to be given) with the naming convention in $(1)$, find lengths of $Y'A',Y'B',Y'M',Y'X'$ from the [angle-bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) in terms of $a',b',c'$ to show $Y'A'\cdot Y'B'=Y'M'\cdot Y'X'$ as an identity in $a',b',c'$.

Comment: How do you take point $C$ ? On the circle with diameter $AB$ ? Moreover "which, **of course**, you can do..." is not evident at all...

Comment: @JeanMarie The point $C$ should lie on the circle with diameter $XY$, [the Appolonius circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius'_definition_of_a_circle). I meant that it is enough to show that in *any* triangle with the mentioned nomenclature of points, the points $A,B,X,Y,M$ satisfy the given equation with products, i.e. the location of points satisfying the equation is determined in either case, whether we are given a triangle (hence it's sides, from where the angle bisector theorem yields all the lengths necessary for computation), or the collinear points.

Comment: I have added a different straightforward solution to this problem too.

Comment: About the first sentence of your comment : why don't you say in your answer that you take $C$ is such a way ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I was hoping you'd point that out, that's because, given $A,B,X,Y$, or even $A,B,X$, I cannot think of a way to construct $C$ such that $CX$ bisects $\angle BCA$ internally, even though I know it should, given the product equation. ...... However, if we draw a figure of a $\Delta ABC$ separate from the line $A,B,X,Y$, to distinguish we should ideally call it something different, say, $\Delta A'B'C'$, whose $\angle C$ bisectors intersect $AB$ at $X',Y'$, $M'$ midpoint of $A'B'$, then the same equation will hold with $A',B',X',Y',M'$. [Let me edit the answer slightly.]

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @JeanMarie I was a bit skeptical of there being some logical fallacy in the answer too, thanks for clearing it out. I have edited the answer to make it a bit clearer now. :)